# Android Studio 3.1 build fails, error while processing drawable

Tags: android

After upgrading to Android Studio 3.1 my project will no longer build, giving me an error pointing to one of my `VectorDrawable`s defined in xml:
`Error while processing /Users/richard/project/app/src/main/res/drawable/name_of_drawable.xml : null`

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will happen if your XML drawable is using unsupported XML attributes. Navigate to the drawable that is reporting the issue and you will probably see an error like: `Attribute endX is only used in API level 24 and higher (current min is 23)`.

There are a few ways to fix this. You can either bump your `minSdkVersion` to a higher version, remove the attributes that are causing the errors, or put the drawable in a specific version resource folder, e.g. `drawable-v24`.

Comment: If you have a convenient reproducible test case, I'd consider filing a bug report, to get them to at least improve that error message. `null` should not be a reason for a build to fail. :-) Anyway, nice analysis!

Comment: @CommonsWare Bug filed: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/76407657 and here is the sample project that reproduces the issue: https://github.com/octohub/StudioBug. Thank you for the kind words! We've come along way since 2013, this is you tearing my app apart during a commonsware campfire LOL: https://imgur.com/GSjeFvn

Comment: "this is you tearing my app apart during a commonsware campfire" -- er, um, yeah, well... I've mellowed some in the intervening years. From the snippet, I probably still don't like what the app was doing, but I'd probably be less animated about it. FWIW, I apologize for my behavior back then.

Comment: Ha, brother, no hard feelings. You were right about the app and I thought it was a funny interaction. Thanks for all the work you do for the Android community and thank you for encouraging me to file the bug. Cheers!

Comment: For me, there was nothing wrong with XML files. It was solved by building again and again after each failure. It's so stupid. I literally changed nothing and at last it got built and ran.